# Automatically run a list of tests in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, mstest

Does anybody know how to automatically run a particular list of tests in the test list manager? We have two lists: a list of unit tests and a list of integration tests. Preferably we would like it to run the tests in the 'unit test' list automatically before it checks in to team system.

We currently have a check-in rule that ensures the particular list of tests has passed before it allows things to be checked in. However, having to open the test list manager, select the appropriate list and run the tests manually each time is driving us to distraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing has been coined `Gated Check-in`, meaning that unless certain configurable criteria are met, the changeset will not be committed.

Unfortunately this feature was not included in TFS 2008, as the only options for check-in triggers were:

- Manual
- Continuous Integration
- Rolling builds
- Schedule

TFS 2010 introduced this functionality. You can read more about it in this article, titled ["TFS 2010 - An Introduction to Gated Check-in"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx). [Define a Gated Check-In Build Process to Validate Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787631%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) describes how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The testdriven.net plugin is awesome - nearly as good as eclipse's built in junit integration.  Is this the type of think you're after?  http://www.testdriven.net/

Comment: thanks but not really what I am after. I want a way to automatically run my list of mstest unit tests when I click the checkin button.